# Finding width of secondary yaxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[quote=yuio1 post_id=168946 time=1627377416 user_id=40637]
Hi

Is there anyway way to get the width of the secondary yaxis in terms of the scale and the label.

For example:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/52792193/127124777-9a194a9b-20b1-4eea-8094-19fc4aa6e6d8.png

This is the sandbox i am using.

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-dual-axes

This is probably simple but I can't see a way of doing it.

I have tried combining multiple values such as  `charts[i]['axes'][1].right`  and `charts[0].plotSizeX`  but it always seems to give a value that is either too large or too small depending on whether the label wraps onto 2 lines. The yAxis width also seems to give the width of the chart, is this expected?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks
[/quote]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the axis width and height by the below calculations:

```
const yAxis = chart.yAxis[1];
const width = chart.chartWidth - (chart.plotLeft + chart.plotWidth + chart.spacing[1]);
const height = yAxis.height;
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dpmcrfLa/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/design-and-style